# Set/Map Tag not compiling in PyAIML

Tags: python, compilation, tags, aiml

I am trying to make a chatbot using AIML and PyAIML and started with a simple script. However I am getting a

PARSE ERROR: Unexpected  tag (line 4, column 23)

when I try to execute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aiml>
<category>
    <pattern>WHAT DOES A <set>ANIMAL</set> SAY</pattern>
        <template>Sound of the animal</template>
</category>
</aiml>
```

Set tag is supported from aiml version 2 and pyaiml0.8.6(which I am using) is the latest release. I have a animal.set file in the same directory.
Similar issues exist for `<map>` tag.

So what am I missing in the compilation of the aiml files? What more info about aiml can be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure if PyAIML supports AIML 2.0. I actually never found any 100% compliant interpreter for AIML.

*Extract from PyAIML website*

> The second goal is 100% compliance with the AIML 1.0.1 standard: no less, but also no more.

If you were working with a C# project I could have recommended SIML - which is light-years ahead of the AIML specification and has an awesome interpreter plus an IDE.

Comment: After exhaustive search I found PyAIML to be incompatible with AIML2.0 
Now I have switched to ProgramAB for parsing.
and I am not working on C#. Thanks for the help anyways :)